# Not functioning desktop

Tags: boot, graphics, 22.04, gui, 22.10

My desktop would just shows nothing but a empty wallpaper. But I find it seems to act correct when I use it as before.(e.g.press the power button,and use arrow key to select yes).I thought it might be a mistake with my system,so **I just reinstated the Ubuntu 22.10** but the problem still exists.Then I **reset the BIOS and erased the whole disk, switched to 22.04LTS**,but the **problem is still there**.How could I solve it.

Comment: what kind of graphics card? How did you install?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics 530. I installed ubuntu in the liveCD environment.But interestingly, all things function well in that environment.